# Update a @ModelAttribute with existing values

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller, modelattribute

I want to know if there's a way to update a existing @ModelAttribute. If possible without keeping the values in session
Let us say I have a bean :

```
class TravelDetails{
    private String origin;
    private String destination;
    private String travelerName;
    private String travelerAge;
        // Getters & Seters
}
```

Here's my controller:

```
@Controller
class TravelerController{

@RequestMapping(value="/searchDetails", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView getSearchDetails(@RequestParam("origin") String origin,
        @RequestParam("destination") String destination,ModelMap modelMap){
    TravelDetails travelDetails = new TravelDetails();
    travelDetails.setOrigin(origin);
    travelDetails.setDestination(destination);
    modelMap.addAttribute("travelDetails",travelDetails);
    return new ModelAndView("get_traveler_details");
    }

@RequestMapping(value="/addTravelerDetails", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView addTravelerDetails(
    @ModelAttribute("travelDetails") TravelDetails travelDetails,
           ModelMap modelMap){
    System.out.println(travelDetails.getOrigin);
    System.out.println(travelDetails.getDestination);
    System.out.println(travelDetails.getTravelerName);
    System.out.println(travelDetails.getTravelerAge);
    return new ModelAndView("get_traveler_details");
    }
   }
```

The the post form obtained in the second controller method only contains the traveler name and age while the origin and destination are required to be retrieved from the model attribute set in first controller.
I don't want to explicitly set set hidden fields in the Post form.

Let's assume my HTML be:

```
<form:form modelAttribute="travelDetails" action="/addTravelerDetails" method="POST">
    <form:input type="text" path="travelerName"/>
    <form:input type="text" path="travelerAge"/>
</form:form>
```

Note : I'm writing the code on StackOverflow's text area and not on some IDE, so if there's some lame spelling or syntax error on code, please ignore.

Comment: you may want to keep the info in session

Comment: No, I don't want to. Would prefer another way if exists.

Comment: why don't you want to send origin destination back? security reasons?

Comment: @sidgate Actually this was just a example. My actual bean have more than 50 attributes. I don't prefer sending the same values again over network + It would increase the JSP.

Comment: @sidgate Any solution? Please tag someone you know who can answer.
Thanks

Comment: you can either get required data from the request, or from session, or some from persistable source. there is no other way.

Comment: Either keep it in the session, send all the information, or use a `@ModelAttribute` annotated method and always send an id and retrieve it from the database. Performance wise I suggest storing it in the session using `@SessionAttributes` (although it actually isn't meant to pass attributes between controllers, but it might work). A database hit for each request isn't really scalable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use @SessionAttributes annotation on the class level

```
@Controller
@SessionAttributes("travelDetailsPersist")
class TravelerController{

    @RequestMapping(value="/searchDetails", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView getSearchDetails(@RequestParam("origin") String origin, @RequestParam("destination") String destination,ModelMap modelMap){
        TravelDetails travelDetails = new TravelDetails();
        travelDetails.setOrigin(origin);
        travelDetails.setDestination(destination);
        modelMap.addAttribute("travelDetails",travelDetails);
        modelMap.addAttribute("travelDetailsPersist",travelDetails);
        return new ModelAndView("get_traveler_details");
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/addTravelerDetails", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView addTravelerDetails(@ModelAttribute("travelDetailsPersist") TravelDetails travelDetailsPersist, @ModelAttribute("travelDetails") TravelDetails travelDetails, ModelMap modelMap){
        System.out.println(travelDetailsPersist.getOrigin);
        System.out.println(travelDetailsPersist.getDestination);
        System.out.println(travelDetails.getTravelerName);
        System.out.println(travelDetails.getTravelerAge);
        return new ModelAndView("get_traveler_details");
    }  
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, But as I already mentioned in the question, I won't prefer to keep values in session.

Comment: Also when you send the model attribute "travelDetailsPersist" to the html page by first controller your "travelDetailsPersist" will act as the model attribute to the form and on submitting the form the same attribute "travelDetailsPersist" will be updated and "travelDetails" attribute will be null. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: and if you don't want to keep it session, you can use your own persistance logic to store and retrieve

Comment: Any hint on how to do that?

Comment: one possible solution might be, you can pass origin and destination from form as a hidden field and then in your addTravelerDetails method you can fetch rest your attributes (you mentioned more than 50) based on origin and destination.

Comment: Or if you have search ID, you can just pass it to addTravelDetails.